# Update node property in neo4j database

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am updating node property through C# using following code, but this code will not update node property. If i run only query part in neo4j browser then it work. Is any another approach to solve this issue?

//Code

```
CypherQuery query = new CypherQuery("
    MATCH (n { Name: \"Person B1\" }) 
    SET n.Name = \"Person  B2\" 
    RETURN n", 
new Dictionary<string, object>(), CypherResultMode.Projection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then probably your match fails.

Does the code actually return the node in question?

You should also use parameters for your data, both for the existing and new ´Name` properties.

And `Person` would most probably be a label.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't at all a supported way of using Neo4jClient. Please try consulting any of the documentation.

Then, the documentation also includes debugging guidance to help you determine what is different between your C# vs. the Cypher you expect.